# (jQuery-Autocomplete) Show all the results after clearing search box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

im fairly new to the jquery and im building an MVC 4 website, this works as expected however I want to handle the event where the user clears the search criteria and then I update my table to its original state

```
    var submitAutoCompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.val(ui.item.label);
    var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
    $form.submit();
};
var createAutoComplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var options = {
        source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete"),
        select: submitAutoCompleteForm
    };
    $input.autocomplete(options);
};
$("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutoComplete);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add this option to require 0 chars to activate the search:

```
minLength:  0
```

With this enabled you can just hit the down-arrow and the list will show

EDIT:

Now that I understand the problem better you will likely need to add the "search" option
The search option fires before anything is requested from the source so it is an optimal place to see if the field is empty or not.

```
,search: function(event, ui){
             if($(this).val() == ''){
                 //code to show table
             }
         }
```

You can also use the change option but in my experience it only fire upon a change in the value or more closely when the field fires a blur event so I do not personally enjoy its'  behavior in my application

```
,change: function(event, ui){
             if($(this).val() == ''){
                 //code to show table
             }
         }
```

Comment: @MonkeyZeus- the autocomplete works fine however lets say after I chose a result and updated my table I wanna show all the results by clearing the search box

Comment: Oh. So you are looking for code to handle your on('submit') event to do an AJAX POST to your database and then populate a html table with every autocomplete option available?

Comment: Is submitAutoCompleteForm a function that you need to call or just a placeholder for currently unknown code?

Comment: hi I've updated my question which contains that part, everything works as expected i just want to handle the event where the user clears the search criteria and then i go ahead and update the table with all the possible results

Comment: Glad I could help you reach a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different approach which is essentially the same thing as @MonkeyZeus suggestion

```
 $("input[type='search']").keyup("search", function () {
    if (!this.value) {
      //code to update the table
```

}
});